# How do I exit from a ARM fault handler?

Tags: arm, handler, stm32

I am using STM32F746, an ARM cortex-M7 based processor. I am trying to do something hacky, which requires me to return to the program from a MemManage Fault handler.

When entering MemManage Fault handler, the PC before the fault and everything I need is stored on the stack. So I thought I can simply recover those to return to the previous execution point.

However, I cannot properly restore the `xPSR`.
The previous `CPSR` before the fault handler is saved in the stack, so I tried restoring it using MSR instruction.
I tried both `MSR, xpsr, r12` and `MSR, apsr, r12`
However, it would only restore the flags and not the other parts of the `CPSR` , such as the `GE` or the system mode bits.
(and my mode bits seems also weird.. my `xPSR` shows as: `0x61070004`, but [this](https://heyrick.eu/armwiki/The_Status_register) tells me that the last 5 bits cannot be `0x04`)

How can I go back to the program point before the fault handler? I also tried popping the pc but it does not work and I think the problem is CPSR not getting properly restored.

Comment: Why are you not reading the Cortex-M7 documentation from ARM? MPU faults are discussed in detail there.

Comment: You'd better solve the problem, why you get in Fault handler, but not the way to get out from it.

Comment: @Bulkin the OP explicitely stated he needs to do something hacky, he gets in the Fault handler on purpose

Comment: @andymango the ARM documentation is far to be crystal clear...

Comment: I never tried to return from a Fault handler (usually you do something "definitive" like resetting, infinite looping or something like this), and I would also have expected that the xPSR is restored. It is described like this at Figure 11 in Cortex M7 programming manual. What is the value of xPSR before and after the Fault handler ?

Comment: "my xPSR shows as: 0x61070004" it means ISR_NUMBER = 4 which is MemManage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a Cortex M7 enters an exception handler, the execution context is saved as follows and of course restored when exiting the handler (from ARM Cortex M7 Programming Manual):

[image]

As you see, the xPSR is restored after the return from exception.

Furthermore

> faults are a subset of the exceptions.

You can do a simple test: dereference on purpose an unvalid pointer. It will trigger a HardFault. Modify your HardFault handler to just return and do nothing. You can check that the context is restored. I tried on STM32H753, it works fine, xPSR latest bits (ISR_NUMBER) are indeed 0 (thread mode).

Be careful though: I don't know for MemManage but HardFault returns to the very same instruction that triggered the fault (and not to the following instruction like a regular exception). It means you will execute again the same instruction after the Hardfault.

Comment: MemManage fault handling is more complicated. Proper handling requires examining the Memory Fault status register and the Memory Fault address registers. Since the question is not clear as to what the fault handler is trying to accomplish (other than something "hacky"), it's hard to know what else is needed beyond a simple return from the exception.

Comment: When I insert "return;" as a C code in my MemManage Handler, it inserts "bx lr" instruction. Inside the MemManage lr holds 0xfffffff9, which is a EXC_RETURN value. By looking at (http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/Babefdjc.html), it seems like when I bx with the EXC_RETURN value the HW must properly find things in the stack and restore it, but it seems like my system is trying to instead bx into the 0xfffffff9 addresss directly? I'm not sure if it is my GDB or my processor actually doing a wrong thing, but it says "Cannot access memory at address 0xfffffff9".

Comment: With some basic tests, I think it is working. I think the GDB just messes it up when I try to step through the "bx lr" insts (which makes my life very uncomfortable, so I must look into it more). Thank you!

Comment: Address 0xfffffff9 has a special meaning, it is not the actual adress of an instruction. See Table 20 in Cortex M7 Prog Manual. This value of EXC_RETURN means "Return to Thread mode, exception return uses non-floating-point state from
MSP and execution uses MSP after return"

Comment: @andymango obviously you're right, it would not make any sense to just return from a fault handler and do nothing. My example was to check and understand how exception entry / return is working